# Unable to start the daemon process Windows 7 Android 3.1 Bulid Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

I installed the new android studio update 3.1 and got this error when i opened my project file.

PC Spec
Windows 7 64bit
AMD FX6300
16GB RAM

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I fixed the issue now, gradle was blocked in my firewall, i unblocked it and now its working.